# How to read specific column under a string from csv file using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I was running a system performance test & I need to check for test results from a CSV file. For example, my test.csv file shared below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUldk4N_5kEAETWdd2B5-x0UOpA_O0aus7x49fEqnPk/edit?usp=sharing

Please note that the results "PASS" or "FAIL" will be a hyperlink.

Issue: I need to check if the driverproblem test is passed or not. For example, if I run 100 cycles, the results under deviceproblem will be listed 100 times. If there is even 1 failure among the 100 cycles, the test is considered fail.

I am able to fetch the values(results) for one row under "driverproblem" field, but i am getting results in hyperlinks for all other fields that are present in the row instead of just one field.

Is there any way, where i can just get the result "PASS" or "FAIL" for fields: "driverproblem" or "Devicemanager" or "Crash"?

I have tried with below:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
for index,row in enumerate(csv_file):
        if "driverproblem" in row.split(','):
            for i in range(10):
                line = csv_file.next().split()
                a= line[2].split(',')
                print a
```

but i am getting results as below:

> ['PASS:Basictest"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""..\..\Reports\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\1.1.1_test_os\Driver_info.xml""', '""PASS"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""..\..\Reports\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\1.1.1_TEST_SYS\drivertest_Log_Delta.xml""', '""PASS"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""..\..\Reports\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\systemtestlogss\systemtestlogs.csv""', '""PASS"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""..\..\Reports\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\systemtestlogss\systemtestlogs.csv""', '""PASS"")"', '"=HYPERLINK(""..\..\Reports\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\systemtestlogss\systemtestlogs.csv""', '""PASS:Connected(via']

whereas i need only the field 
`""=HYPERLINK(""..\\..\\Reports\\testreport_03-20-19-07-37-01\\1.1.1_TEST_SYS\\drivertest_Log_Delta.xml""', '""PASS"")"` which is under "Drivertest" field in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("test.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
        arr = []
        crash = []
        devicemanager = []
        for row in csv_file:                              
                rowarr = row.split(',')
                arr.append(rowarr)
                devicemanager.append(rowarr[5])
                crash.append(rowarr[7])
```

Output:

> ```
> ['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'Crash\n', 'PASS\n', 'NA']
> ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'Devicemanager', 'PASS', 'NA']
> ```

You can iterate through the lists crash and device manager to find the fields PASS and FAIL. Note that this is columns 5 and 7 of test.csv.

```
Total No Of Cycles,2,,,,,,
Passed Cycles,2,,,,,,
Failed Cycles,0,,,,,,
Ignored Cycles,0,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
Cycle Number,Cycle PASS/FAIL,Expected State,Test,Driver problem,Devicemanager,Memory Dump,Crash
1,PASS,S4,PASS:S4,PASS,PASS,PASS,PASS
2,PASS,S4,PASS:S4,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

**DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date.** ***source: repl.it***

For a cleaner version, use the csv module--it's quicker to write code with it:

```
import csv

csv_file_path = 'test.csv'
csvFile = open(csv_file_path,'r')
csvrdr = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
devicemanager = []
crash = []
for row in csvrdr:
    devicemanager.append(row[5])
    crash.append(row[7])


print(crash)
print(devicemanager)
```

Output:

> ```
> ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'Crash', 'PASS', 'NA']
> ['', '', '', '', '', '', 'Devicemanager', 'PASS', 'NA']
> ```

Both of these examples will work on python 2 and 3, so you should consider upgrading to python 3, as python 2 is being deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know another way of doing it. I somehow got it sorted using pandas: 

file = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv",skiprows=20,usecols=["Devicemanager","driverproblem"]

This gives the output in array form which can be converted to list using numpy:

import numpy as np

convert_to_list = np.array(file).tolist()

Comment: Okay great! 